# Рекурсивное удаление файлов с выборкой по содержащимся в имени файла символам (словам) в windows

Tags: windows, bat, консоль

Заголовок самодостаточен. К примеру, получилось рекурсивно удалить файлы по расширению таким образом `del /S *.tmp`, а вот с содержанием определённой строки в названии файла не выходит. Подсобите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Что, и файловые маски в аргументах DEL не работают? Почему-то слабо верится :)

Comment: Однако благодаря Вашему комментарию, нашёл таки решение ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вот скриптик вышел для удаления файлов Dropbox-а.

`Set "FilterEn=*'s conflicted copy 20*"
Set "FilterRu=*(Конфликтующая копия с компьютера*"
del /S "%FilterEn%" >> out.txt
del /S "%FilterRu%" >> out.txt
del /S *.tmp >> out.txt
pause`